# ZeroMQ PUB/SUB topology on the same machine

Tags: java, zeromq, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe, distributed-system

Is it possible for a publisher to publish to multiple clients on the same machine using ZeroMQ? I'd like a set of clients, each of which can make standard Request/Response calls using SocketType.**REQ** and SocketType.**REP**, but which can also receive notifications using SocketType.**SUB** and SocketType.**PUB**.

I've tried to implement this topology, taken from [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/java:chapter2), although my version only has one publisher.

[image]

Here is my publisher:

```
public class ZMQServerSmall 
{   
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try (ZContext context = new ZContext()) 
        {           
            ZMQ.Socket rep = context.createSocket(SocketType.REP);
            rep.bind("tcp://*:5555");

            ZMQ.Socket pub = context.createSocket(SocketType.PUB);
            pub.bind("tcp://*:7777");           

            while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
            {                   
                String req = rep.recvStr(0);
                rep.send(req + " response");

                pub.sendMore("Message header");
                pub.send("Message body");;          
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my proxy (I included a Listener to try to see what's going on):

```
public class ZMQForwarderSmall 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {       
        try 
        (
            ZContext context = new ZContext();   
        )
        {
            ZMQ.Socket frontend = context.createSocket(SocketType.XSUB);            
            frontend.connect("tcp://*:7777");

            ZMQ.Socket backend = context.createSocket(SocketType.XPUB);
            backend.bind("tcp://*:6666");

            IAttachedRunnable runnable = new Listener();
            Socket listener = ZThread.fork(context, runnable);

            ZMQ.proxy(frontend, backend, listener);
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        } 
    }

    private static class Listener implements IAttachedRunnable 
    {    
        @Override
        public void run(Object[] args, ZContext ctx, Socket pipe) 
        {
            while (true) 
            {
                ZFrame frame = ZFrame.recvFrame(pipe);
                if (frame == null)
                    break; // Interrupted
                System.out.println(frame.toString());
                frame.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Subscriber:

```
public class ZMQClientSmall
{   
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        String input;

        try 
        (
            ZContext context = new ZContext();
            BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))
        ) 
        { 
            ZMQ.Socket reqSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.REQ);
            reqSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:5555");

            ZMQ.Socket subSocket = context.createSocket(SocketType.SUB);
            subSocket.connect("tcp://localhost:6666");

            subSocket.subscribe("".getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET));

            while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
            {
                reqSocket.send(input.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET), 0);
                String response = reqSocket.recvStr(0);

                String address = subSocket.recvStr(ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
                String contents = subSocket.recvStr(ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
                System.out.println("Notification received: " + address + " : " + contents);
            }
        }   
    }   
}
```

Here is the test. I open four terminals; 1 publisher, 1 proxy, and 2 clients. When I make a request in either of the two client terminals, I expect to see a notification in both, but instead I only see the notification in the terminal that made the request. I know that both clients are using the same address (localhost:6666), but I'd hoped that the proxy would solve that problem.

Can anyone see anything obviously wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *Is it possible for a publisher to publish to multiple clients on the same machine using ZeroMQ?*

Oh **sure**, it is. No doubts about that.

---

Check the code. The responsibility of the order-of-execution is there. In **[distributed-systems](/questions/tagged/distributed-systems)** this always so.

Once the **`[Client]-No1` instance** gets a plausible `.readLine()`-ed `input` it will jump-in:

```
        while ((input = stdIn.readLine()) != null)
        {
            reqSocket.send(input.getBytes(ZMQ.CHARSET), 0);
            String response = reqSocket.recvStr(0);

            String address = subSocket.recvStr(ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
            String contents = subSocket.recvStr(ZMQ.DONTWAIT);
            System.out.println(           "Notification received: "
                              + address + " : "
                              + contents
                                );
        }
```

Next it `.send()`-s over `REQ` and blocks (awaiting `REP` response)

Given the **`[Client]-No2` instance** also gets a plausible manual `.readLine()`-ed `input` it will jump-in the same `while(){...}`, yet it will not proceed any farther than into again blocking wait for **`REP`**-response. That will not get `.recv()`-ed any time but after the **`-No1`** got served from the `REP`-side, so while the `-No1` might have gotten out of the blocking-`.recv()`, not so the **`-No2`** ( which will still hang inside the its blocking-`.recv()` for any next `REP`-side response ( which may come but need not ), while the **`No1`** has already proceeded to the **`PUB/SUB-.recv()`**, which it will receive ( but ***never* the `No2`** ), next rushing into the next blocking-`input`-feed from `.readLine()` <sub>*Et Cetera, Et Cetera, Et Cetera, ..., **Ad Infinitum***</sub>

So, these **`SEQ`**-of-In-Loop (`REQ`)-parts followed by (`SUB`)-parts in whatever number **`N > 1`** of **`[Client]`**-instances, have effectively generated **an EXCLUSIVE Tick-Tock-Tick-Tock clock-machine**, mutually blocking an exclusive delivery of the **`PUB`**-ed in an **`N`**-interleaved order ( not speaking about the manual, `.readLine()`-driven, blocking step )

The **`ZMQServerSmall`** is not aware about anything wrong, as it `.send()`-s in-order to any `.recvStr()`-ed counterparty over `REQ/REP` and `PUB`-s to all counterparties ( that do not read autonomously, but only after 've been manually `.readLine()` unblocked and only then ( after `REQ/REP` episodic ( potentially infinitely blocked ) steps ) may `.recv()` its next ( so far not read message-part ( yet, there I do not see any code that works with explicitly handling the presence / absence of the multipart-flags on the `SUB`-side `.recv()` operations )

```
        while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) 
        {                   
            String req = rep.recvStr(0);
            rep.send(req + " response");

            pub.sendMore("Message header");
            pub.send("Message body");;          
        }
```

The `ZMQServerSmall` in the meantime sends ( N - 1 )-times more messages down the **`PUB`**-broadcast lane, so the Tick-Tock-Tick-Tock MUTEX `REQ/SUB`-loop-blocking "pendulum" is not 2-State, but **`N`**-State on the receiving sides ( all receive the same flow of `PUB`-ed messages,
yet ***interleaved* by the N-steps of the `REQ/REP` MUTEX-*stepping*** )

Comment: Great answer, thanks, so much to think about.

Of course, I forgot that the REQ.recv is a blocking call!

So, what's a good way around this? It seems to me that the easiest solution is to put the REQ socket and the SUB socket on separate threads. Are there any other ways?

Comment: @PaulHennessey Another rule of thumb - StackOverflow strongly discourages Community Members from creeping the original Question focus -- asking a new fairly formulated Question is conform to the set of Community Rules, so do not hesitate to follow it

Comment: Well, I guess that's fair - I asked why it wasn't working, and now I know :)

Thanks again.